# System.ObjectDisposedException. What is the proper way to handle stream writer?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Here is my code, self-explanatory. After `using` block terminates - `output` variable being disposed. Why? I want to return it from function, what is the proper way to dispose StreamWriter but return my object?

```
public static Stream Write(Interchange interchange)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output))
    {
        foreach (var rawSegment in GetRawSegments(interchange))
        {
            writer.Write(rawSegment.ToString(interchange.ElementDelimeter, interchange.SegmentTerminator));
        }

        writer.Flush();
     }

     return output;
}
```

Comment: **TextWriter** writer = new StreamWriter ???

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi That's fine - `StreamWriter` is a subclass of `TextWriter`.

Comment: @ReedCopsey OK. Just never seen it before. Guess I learn everyday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [constructor for StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853.aspx) which allows you to specify, via a `bool`, to not close the underlying `Stream`:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
{
```

Note that you may also want to reset the position of the `MemoryStream` to zero before returning it, depending on how it'll be used.

Comment: Is it .NET 4.5 specific?

Comment: @alexm yes, in earlier versions of .NET it would always close the underlying stream.

Answer (score 2):

StreamWriter does not have unmanaged resources besides the stream to dispose of. Calling TextWriter.Dispose() results in closing the underlying stream. To keep the stream open remove `using` block:

```
var output = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output);
foreach (var rawSegment in GetRawSegments(interchange))
{
   writer.Write(rawSegment.ToString(interchange.ElementDelimeter, interchange.SegmentTerminator));
}

writer.Flush();

return output;
```

PS: For .NET 4.5 and above Reed's answer looks more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, create new instance, when it's necessary...

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\\Documents\Dev\error.txt", true))
{
    writer.WriteLine("cod: " + codERP );
}
```

Steamwriter automaticaly close file.

try get all information you need (inside for) after write in your file(once time)